# Tailwind Css Flexbox Justify-between doesn't work as expected

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to implement navigation with Tailwind but, doesn't result as expected

```
<nav class="bg-gray-100">
        <div class="flex flex-row justify-between w-full">
            <div>
                <div>Logo</div>
                <div>Primary Nav</div>
            </div>
            <div>Menu</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

This is the result I want:

[image]

Comment: It's working as it should what is your expected outcome, if you want space between Logo and Primary Nav then flex the parent div

Comment: Hello, I want the menu div to the end of the screen.

Comment: I already updated my question

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/BeXCFpgWTA

Comment: @DennyKurniawan Your code working. You included entire tailwindCss to your application? if no, maybe you need to redo your css.

Comment: Hello I am using Laravel Mix, I am pretty sure CSS and JS are loaded successfully.

Comment: @MaikLowrey I run npm run watch again, and its success, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @DennyKurniawan You welcome! I wrote my comment as an answer so you could mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to regenerate your css. In the development process, however, it is recommended to always work with the whole TailwindCSS file. For the production you can purge unnecessary css.
Means:
`npm run dev` or start `npm run watch`.

Comment: Yes, that's it Laravel will auto regenerate the CSS files with the npm command.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using this would be,

```
<nav class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="flex justify-between">
        // your html
    </div>
</nav>
```

Check the docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content)